# Executing a query on a large SQLite DB in python for the first time takes very long

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a relatively large sqlite db (~2 GB). I'm running a simple SELECT query on it and it roughly takes 2 min to run. Any similar query after first execution takes less than a second.

I did some google and apparently this condition is known as 'cold cache/warm cache' behavior. In which at the first attempt, each byte is physically read from the hard disk (cold cache) and this is a slow task. On the next attempts, it simply retrieve data from RAM buffers (warm cache).

However, on my SELECT statement I'm just selecting a few tables with certain conditions. Does sqlite need to transfer ALL the database to RAM first before running any query? Is there any way around it or it's just the way it works?

Thanks for any comment

P.S. I tried VACUUM and ANALYZE but didn't improve execution time.

Comment: How much of the file has to be read depends on your query, what tables are used, how big they are, any indexes, etc. But yes, if none of the file is in the OS level filesystem cache, much less sqlite's page cache, it's going to be slower than if it is.

Comment: @Shawn I have around 200,000 tables and each table around 100 rows and 4 columns. All indexed. The problem is when I run `cursor.execute("ANY QUERY")` for the first time it takes 2 min. Any execution after that takes a second. So it's just the way sqlite behaves and there's nothing I can do about it?

Comment: **200,000** tables? No wonder it's slow. That sort of mammoth table count is usually a sign of a poor understanding of how relational databases should be structured - things like having tens of thousands of otherwise identical small tables, one per some entity, instead of using a single table for all of them. In the case of sqlite, it's doubly bad because the first time a statement is prepared on a newly opened database, it has to parse every single table definition from the `sqlite_master` table - all **200,000** of them. Only taking 2 minutes is kind of impressive, actually.